# Why are my keyboard events processed after the method completes?

Tags: c#, winforms

After clicking a button, I am trying to:

- Move a cursor to an input box.
- Click the box.
- Pause for x time.
- Type "1".
- Pause for x time.
- Type "2" in the box.

... The end result should be "12" in the box.

When I run the program without any delays, it works as intended... albeit fast.

When I try to put a delay between the 1 and 2, I see no click or keyboard events get processed and appear on the form until the method finishes. The textbox changes will go from 2, to 4, to 6.

After textbox reaching 6, "12" will appear in the input box. This looks to me like for both times, no events take place until all the code within the method has finished executing.

With my limited knowledge, I am trying to understand:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How I can pause in the middle of the method between events without
   freezing the entire form?
3. How can I have each event appear before the next event as opposed to all events happening when the method finishes?

```
public void DelayTimer(int interval)
        {
            Task.Delay(interval).Wait();
        }
private void typeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CursorMovementToPoint(PointToScreen(new Point((typeBox.Location.X + (typeBox.Size.Width / 2)), (typeBox.Location.Y + (typeBox.Size.Height / 2))))); // Moves cursor to center of Box
            textBox1.Text = "1"; // Indicates event 1 is done
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0); // Clicks on box
            textBox1.Text = "2"; // Indicates event 2 is done
            DelayTimer(1000); // Pauses for 1 sec
            textBox1.Text = "3"; // Indicates pause is done
            keybd_event(KEY_1, KEY_1_SCAN, 0, 0); // Types "1" into Box
            textBox1.Text = "4";
            DelayTimer(1000); // Pauses for 1 sec between typing "1" and before typing "2"
            textBox1.Text = "5";
            keybd_event(KEY_2, KEY_2_SCAN, 0, 0); // Types "2" into Box
            textBox1.Text = "6"; // Finished
        }
```

Comment: you must put event in a thread.

Comment: You're running your event handler, including the delays, on the UI thread. The same UI thread that's needed to process e.g. keyboard events. You don't release the UI thread to do other work until your method is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button.Click` handler is now declared `async`.
The `DelayTimer()` method was removed and a delay was placed directly in the `typeButton_Click` event handler.
This essentially changed the delay from `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();` to `await Task.Delay(1000);`:

```
private async void typeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CursorMovementToPoint(PointToScreen(new Point((typeBox.Location.X + (typeBox.Size.Width / 2)), (typeBox.Location.Y + (typeBox.Size.Height / 2)))));
    SendM(MOUSEEVENTF.LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF.LEFTUP);
    textBox1.Text = "1";
    await Task.Delay(1500);

    SendK(ScanCodeShort.KEY_1);
    textBox1.Text = "2";
    await Task.Delay(1500);

    SendK(ScanCodeShort.KEY_2);
    textBox1.Text = "3";
}
```

This resolved the issue: the events were not processed until the method was completed, the Form is not blocked and other events can be processing (now I can also close the Form while a delay is active).
I also added `SendInput()` to replace my previous methods to call mouse and keyboard events but that was unrelated to the delay issues. Works for me.